# SQL Data-Tier Application - Export vs. Extract

Tags: sql-server-2014

What is the difference between the "Extract data-tier application" and "Export data-tier application" in the SSMS Options when right-clicking on a database?

Comment: Whoever names these functions should be fired.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So apparently "Export" creates a `.bacpac` file and "Extract" creates a `.dacpac` file.

After trying both options and seeing they had different file types, I found this information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx);

*DACPAC and BACPAC are similar but they target different scenarios. A DACPAC is focused on capturing and deploying schema, including upgrading an existing database. The primary use case for a DACPAC is to deploy a tightly defined schema to development, test, and then to production environments. And also the reverse: capturing production’s schema and applying it back to test and development environments.*

A BACPAC, on the other hand, is focused on capturing schema and data supporting two main operations:

- **EXPORT**– The user can export the schema and the data of a database to a BACPAC.
- **IMPORT** – The user can import the schema and the data into a new database in the host server.

Both these capabilities are supported by the database management tools: SQL Server Management Studio, the Azure Portal, and the DACFx API.

*tl;dr* = ***Extract is used for schema information, Export is used for schema  information and data.***